byte like object error when checking encrypted passwords (Python)
I am creating an application that requires a user login. The username and password must be stored in a database, but I don't want to store them as plane text. I followed this  tutorial on how to store passwords securely on a database. I am using the code from the tutorial except I made some changes to use pyodbc instead of their SQL library.
To create a username and password, I am using this code, which works great and posts to the db:
import pyodbc
import os
import hashlib
  
PEPPER = "SECRET_KEY" 

def create_user(username, password):
    
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
            r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + db_path + ";"
        ) 

    cursor = conn.cursor()
   
    # Generate secure hash
    password_hash = create_secure_password(password)  

    # Split hash into components
    salt, key = password_hash[:16], password_hash[16:]
    hash_algo = "sha256"
    iterations = 100_000

    # Insert into database
    info = (username, key, salt, hash_algo, iterations)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Login_Info ([username], [password_hash], [salt], [hash_algo], [iterations] ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", info)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def create_secure_password(password):
  salt = os.urandom(16)  
  iterations = 100_000
  hash_value = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256',password.encode('utf-8') + PEPPER.encode('utf-8'),  salt, iterations)  
  password_hash = salt + hash_value
  return password_hash 

The database entry shows up like this:
Username and password in the db
However, when I use the method to check a username and password against the database, I get this error:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
The error is for this line of code, which I believe converts the entered password into a hash to compare with the database hash
password_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(hash_algo, password.encode('utf-8'), salt, iterations)
The full code for the login method is as follows:
def login(username, password):
    #connect to DB
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
            r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + db_path + ";"
        ) 

    cursor = conn.cursor()
 
    # Define your SQL query
    select_sql = "SELECT * FROM Login_Info WHERE username = ?"

    # Execute the query using the cursor
    cursor.execute(select_sql, (username,))

    # Fetch one row of result
    account = cursor.fetchone()


    if not account:
        print("Invalid username")
        return
 
    salt, db_key, hash_algo, iterations = account[2:6]



    # Recompute hash from user entered password
    password_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(hash_algo, password.encode('utf-8'), salt, iterations)
 
    # Compare hashes
    if password_hash == db_key:
        print("Login successful")
    else:
        print("Invalid password")

I have tried finding other resources online, but couldn't find anyone with this exact problem

Can't reproduce as I don't have your database, but ensure the data you put in is the data you get out.  If I eliminate the database and just pass the values generated by create_user back into hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac, it doesn't give that error.  It doesn't validate either. I had to add + PEPPER.encode('utf-8') to the password.

So it most likely is my database? As of now it returns everything from the database as a string, is this correct?

What do the strings look like?  Are the bytes objects or str?  I'm guessing you get back "b'xxxxxxxx'" (the str of a bytes object) and that's why you get that error.  Store the bytes objects as .hex() instead and use bytes.fromhex() to convert back to bytes once you receive the strings from the database.

Thank you so much for the quick response.
Yes my main issue is that I'm getting back the bytes as a string. What do you mean by .hex()? How do I convert the bytes to hex?

Nevermind, I think I understand what you mean

You fixed it, by converting the key and salt into hex before storing it in the database, I was able to properly pull the data and convert it back to bytes

I don't believe the data inserted as bytes objects are being retrieved as bytes objects, but I don't have your database.  One solution is to store str objects obtained from the bytes.hex() method and convert them back to bytes objects after extraction from the database.
Also + PEPPER was missing from the recomputed hash.
Below is a minimal verified example that removes the database and works with strings:
import os
import hashlib

PEPPER = b'SECRET_KEY'  # bytes object so no need to .encode()

def create_user(username, password):
    salt, key = create_secure_password(password)
    hash_algo = 'sha256'
    iterations = 100_000

    # Insert these items into database.
    return username, key, salt, hash_algo, iterations

def create_secure_password(password):
    salt = os.urandom(16)
    iterations = 100_000
    hash_value = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256',password.encode() + PEPPER,  salt, iterations)
    return salt.hex(), hash_value.hex()  # Use hex strings, not bytes objects

def login(username, password):

    # Simulate data retrieved from database
    _, db_key, salt, hash_algo, iterations = create_user(username, password)

    # Recompute hash from user entered password.
    # Convert salt to bytes, then the hash to hex.
    # Added missing PEPPER.
    password_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(hash_algo, password.encode() + PEPPER, bytes.fromhex(salt), iterations).hex()
 
    # Compare hashes as strings.
    if password_hash == db_key:
        print('Login successful')
    else:
        print('Invalid password')

login('mark', 'abc')

Output:
Login successful


When saving the key and salt to the database, I was storing it as a string. Therefore, access returned the entire byte as a string. Instead save the key and salt as a hex value as such:
info = ((username), key.hex(), salt.hex(), str(hash_algo), str(iterations))
then when retrieving the information, you must convert them back to bytes by using:
db_key = bytes.fromhex(db_key)
salt = bytes.fromhex(salt)

@user23346328 That's what this example shows minus actually putting the strings into and out of the database.  Upvote and accept if it helped.
